# why getting “No Persistence provider for EntityManager” when running with jnlp while standalone jar works fine

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, eclipselink

Environment
Win 8.1
MySQL server: localhost
Netbeans 7.4
Java: 1.7.0_51 (J2SE)
JRE: 1.7.0_51-b31
EclipseLink(JPA 2.1)

There are several posts asking about this “no persistence provider for EntityManager named…” error. I am developing with J2SE (not J2EE). However, my problems seem silly but it really troubles me for 2days. Is it that I need some other software for this standalone program to work? But why is it oaky when I run the program under Netbeans IDE? Is it some sort of environment setting issue which I failed to try?

Working snapshot and EclipseLink message!
[image]

I use Netbeans to write code, and it runs okay. Now, I decided to copy the whole standalone package out “D:\NetBeansWork\ProjCostTracking\dist”.  I have change the security setting to medium in Java Control Panel.  Then, I double-clicked on ProjCostTracking.jnlp to launch. Well, this is what I see.

[image]

this is my persistence.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
      <persistence-unit name="ProjCostTrackingPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>ProjCostTracking.EntityUserlevel</class>
        <class>ProjCostTracking.EntityUser</class>
        <properties>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/biotechcost?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="1234"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        </properties>
      </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

The entity files are
[image]

The generated files and lib
[image]
[image]

As for persistence.xml, I copy to 3 places just to make sure it can be “seen”.
[image]

As for CLASSPATH, I copied the required jar files (from ProjCostTracking\dist\lib) to lib folder under my default JDK and JRE. So java suppose to see the jars. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: NEVER copy jars into the JVM. It will mess with your other projects. Add them to the classpath variable/parameter. Or, in netbeans, you can define them as runtime libraries (or something like that, it has been long time since I used it)

Comment: it's just a test to show that CLASSPATH is not the concern here.

Comment: Try setting EclipseLink logging to finest and see if it is even getting that far or if some problem is preventing the persistence unit from loading: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging

Comment: Not really solve the jnlp issue, but it's nice to have detail log though :) thx

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is a connector issue.
It seems that eclipse is not using the right connector. Check the connector version. It should  match with the version of your MySQL database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. can you further explain connector version should match MySQL version? Shouldn't the connector issue also be affecting my program when I run it under Netbean (if connector is the root cause)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am using JNLP in a wrong way. Because when I run the standalone with "java -jar myprogram.jar" it works perfectly, no error. But, when I use jnlp it gives me the error. Hope I am not misleading everyone here. It is more related to how jnlp works with the persistence stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that if you want to use Application Managed Entity Manager you have to control the scope of the drivers and used APIs.

For example: in a Java SE Application you can build the project with maven. The Scope of the dependencies signals when the API or the package has to be used. E.g.

```
    (...)    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    (...)
```

Because the life circle is managed by the application and not by the container (like in Java EE applications).
In my case it was important to change the scope from `provided` to `runtime` (Same with the database driver). In your case - if you are not using maven you are dependent what the JVM is using.

Maybe this is helpful. I know this kind of issues and it is really annoying :|

[Maven Scope Doc](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Dependency+Scopes)

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for the reply. You mentioned something I haven't try yet. Can you further illustrate on how do I know (or change) what the JVM is using for the driver? I think all the available jars are under the radar of CLASSPATH. Thanks